# Linux equivalent of Terminals ~ http://terminals.codeplex.com/

Tags: linux

Any Linux equivalents of [Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/)?

There isn't anything listed on alternativeto.net. :(

http://alternativeto.net/software/terminals/?platform=linux

Comment: that site show you similar software, not equivalents.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia maybe you don't speak english. If it's very very similar then it is hopefully equivalent. So sometimes almong the alternatives, there can be an equivalent, though apparently not in this case

Comment: @barlop i try(you refill my mood today ty :))

Answer (score 3):

The one I'm most familiar with is [Vinagre](http://projects.gnome.org/vinagre/), but its RDP plugin is still beta quality.  Ubuntu is switching to [Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/), though.

Comment: this is the answer,

Answer (score 2):

I often use [gnome-rdp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnome-rdp/) on Ubuntu.